# Is there an adjectival form of the word "personality"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is "**personal**" the right adjective for the noun "**personality**" in the context of "of a type of personality" ? If **personal** is not the right adjective, is there another word for it.

**contrived examples**

> (a) The drastic difference in people's reactions to the event is attributed to the differences in their cultural backgrounds and their **personalities**
>
> (b) The drastic difference in people's reactions to the event is attributed to their cultural and **personal** differences.
>
> (c) For reasons that were attributed to by a difference in the **personalities** among team members, team A succeeded in finishing the task before the deadline while team B failed to complete the task.
>
> (d) Due to **personal** differences among team members, team A succeeded in finishing the task before the deadline while team B failed to complete the task

Comment: It depends on the context of the word *personality*.  Are you talking about the character of a person or are you talking about a celebrity or famous person?

Comment: Provide your sense of *personality*. My immediate reaction is that *personalized* works better than *personal* (although it's still not quite right)—but I don't know how you want to use *personality*. Please provide an example sentence.

Comment: You mean "Is there an adjectival form?" After all, *adjective* is a noun. :)

Comment: Yes. title has been edited.

Comment: @BChen Thanks for the edit! Not only does it read better now, it clarifies that you’re interested in how to go about deriving an adjectival form starting from the word *personality* under the various standard and easily recognized rules of derivational morphology. And perhaps you’d like to know if such a derived term already exists in English.This allows your refocussed question to attract more scholarly and inspired answers, which is the very sort we most want. I assure you that such answers are possible here but have not yet been given. Perhaps tonight I shall try.

Comment: @tchrist, I meant to edit my question to reflect my own comment to user22542's answer. So yes, I am curious how we can derive an "adjectival form" from the word "personality". Your response now triggers a second question - are there many examples where "-ality" or "-lity" nouns (seem to) differ from their adjectival forms in their meanings.

Answer (score 2):

For the type of example given in your question, *personality* must be used as a [noun adjunct](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).  There is no special “adjectival form”, although you could construct an artificial one in order to achieve a certain tone.

A person’s *personality* is a combination of many elements, almost like a [portfolio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portfolio_(finance)), and as a word it functions the same way.

For example, the [Myers-Briggs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Briggs_Type_Indicator) and [Big Five](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) models start with a set of “traits” that are all present to some degree.

When you use *personality* as an adjective, you are saying that the noun it modifies is qualified by its association with a *set* of things, which includes all of the possible relationships amongst them, as well as their individual natures. Thus, a team might fail because of *personality differences* or *personality clashes* amongst its members, but it could also fail as a result of *personality deficits* that all of its members have in common (lack of openness to new experience, for example).

There are many nouns in English that refer to collections, and which don’t have a commonly used adjectival form.

For example,  *rain* has the simple adjective *rainy*, but the collection of phenomena referred to as *weather* does not have an equivalent form. One could speak of “weatherish delays” on a sea voyage or “a weatherly choice of overcoat”, but these are contrived forms intended to draw attention, not words that would be generally used.

Comment: You are not using *personality* as an adjective when you use a noun to modify another noun. That's why talking about *an extremely personality trait* is ungrammatical. If that were an adjective like *personal* it would have been fine but it's not. It's still a noun. See the difference? Compare *an extremely personal trait* with *an extreme personality trait*.

Answer (score 0):

As a derivative of the word "**personal**" the adjective "**personalized**" can be contextually used.

The adjective "**individual**" would also convey the meaning that you seek in your examples. There are some other synonyms that might work as well.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/personalized

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/individual

https://www.freethesaurus.com/individual

Comment: Agree. But then we'd be talking about synonyms, not a derivative of the word "personality", whose Latin root is personalis, of a person. I was simply curious if there is an adjective in modern English for "personality", as in my impression, the modern usage and understanding of the word "personal" seems to deviate far away from "personality".